# PHP namespaces and autoloading

Tags: php, namespaces, spl-autoload-register

I'm rather new to PHP or to be more specify new to projects that is at least a bit complex and has a lot of classes. Up till now using require_once was ok. However on a new project it is getting a bit messy with tons of includes of which not all are always required.

What I'm creating is a client for a complex public web service (which is not in my control). That client will then be used in applications.

I looked at spl_autoload_register but not really getting it to work. The directory of this project is:

```
webServiceClient/src/path/same/as/namespaces
```

lets say the class of the client that will be directly by applications used is in

```
webServiceClient/src/path/same
```

That class must "load" all possible required classes. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Look at PSR-0 (https://gist.github.com/1234504) proposal. Maybe It will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create autoload function
2. Register point 1 function into `spl_autoload_register`.
   [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php)
3. If you just have `__autoload` as autoload function, you have not to
   register it. [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php)
4. Write your autoload function

.

```
function __autoload($classname) {    
   $filename = ROOT."\\". $classname .".php"; //you can define ROOT by define('ROOT','dir path');    
   include_once($filename);    
}
```

So, when you declare

```
$myclass = new webServiceClient\src\path\same;
```

autolaod will include `ROOT.'webServiceClient\src\path\same.php'`

Comment: '/' is not a namespace separator. Valid namespace separator is '\', and I'm not sure if Your autoloader will handle it properly.